# C - coding string generating algorithm efficiently

Tags: c, string

Here's one of those problems that would be a piece of cake in any higher-level language but when it comes to coding it in pure C, I have no idea what to do in order not to turn my code into a mess:

I have an alphabet of unique letters, and a string with some numbers, e.g. "test01test21". I need to generate all strings that result from replacing the numbers with letters (so each number 0,1,2,... gets its letter (not necessarily unique) and we need to iterate through all possible letter-number replacements in order to generate all strings), and return those strings in some kind of way.

Problem seems easy but the more I think about it, the more problematic it gets. When it comes to returning the result, I have already coded dynamic string-list structure so it isn't the main problem. What I'm wondering about is how to iterate through all letter-number replacements (keep in mind, the number-set is not constant, the numbers to replace in one string might be {0,1,2} and in other one {3,7,9} for example, but it's always some set of digits), here are few ways of doing that I've thought about:

1. We could make 10 nested for loops which iterate through the alphabet for each of 10 possible digits to replace. Problems with this - it's highly uncode'able and does too much unnecessary  computation.
2. We could make false-initialized array of 10 elements at the very beginning, scan through the string, mark all present digits, copy them to other array. Now the initial array would serve as a digit-letter map, and the second array (number-set) would serve us somehow as "iterator helper" (we must somehow iterate through the numbers as in point 1., only this time there will be |number-set| nested for-loops instead of 10 for-loops). Problems with this - I don't still don't know how to code that iteration through number-set and as you can see it gets complicated really quickly even in text - I don't want to think about what would happen if I were to code it in C.

I really can't think about anything else. I think both of these ways are flawed and lead to really complicated code. The question is - what to do when you must solve the problem of this kind in C? I would be thankful for any tips that would help me code this up and somehow organize the code...

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

alphabet "ab"

string "ab01"

output {"abaa","abab","abba","abbb"}

Comment: make an array of pointers of which each element points to a digit in the string? this really just seems the problem of generating variations with repetition…

Comment: Please give some more explanation what is "all strings". Some example string and what the output should be.

Comment: Do all these strings actually need to be in memory at some point (as in actually stored as different strings)? Basically, my question boils down to "how many different digits are there?". If it's always less that 5, you may go with actually generating the strings. If it may be up to 10, you have no chance with generating all of them (and _store_ them), as there are 141'167'095'653'376 combinations (lower case only).

Comment: I need to get all these strings in my code at some point, not necessarily all at once.

Comment: @stefan It may be up to 10 only theoretically, in reality I know there will be smaller number of digits in input string, but those digits will be all from set {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant you're right, it's exactly this problem, but I don't know how to iterate through all those variations. E.g. let's say we have this array of pointers and all possible letters, what next?

Comment: The number of possible replacement combinations if no 2 digits can be replaced by the same letter is `n!/(n-p)!` where `n` is the number of possible letters in the alphabet (upto 26) and `p` is the number of actual different digits appearing in the string (2 in your example).  If, as in your example, different digits can be replaced by the same letter, it is simpler: `pow(n,p)`.

Comment: @qiubit the simplest solution IMO is to regard each particular variation as a number in base-N, where N is the maximal number of distinct letters. Then, iterate in the range [0, N^K) where K is the number of digits to be replaced. The i-th digit then can be computed using division and modulo, as if you were converting an arbitrary integer to an arbitrary base (I'm sure you've written one of those algorithms already).

Comment: @qiubit see my answer below.

Comment: is the string string "ab00" supposed to produce the same output as "ab01"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `tries` data structure. Just start reading your string and build the `tries`.
Let's take your example, it should be like this.

```
    a             a
    |             |
    b             b
    |            / \
    0    -->    a   b
    |          / \ /  \
    1         a   b    a
              |   |    |
             \0  \0   \0
```

character by character build of tries in above example:

```
a ------ b -------  0 -------  1 ------- \0

a ---->  a ------>  a ------>  a ------>   a 
|        |          |          |           |
\0      >b          b          b           b
         |         / \        / \         / \
        \0      >a    b      a   >b      a   b
                 |    |     / \   |     / \ / \
                \0   \0    a   b  \0   a   b   a
                          |   |        |   |   |
                         \0   \0       \0  \0  \0

                              |
                              |
                              v

                              a
                              |
                              b
                            /  \
                           a    b
                          / \  / \
                         a    b   a 
                         |    |   |  
                        \0   \0  \0
```

Now all you have to do is to just traverse the tries. 
Check these useful links for help: [1](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/trie/) [2](http://simplestcodings.blogspot.in/2012/11/trie-implementation-in-c.html)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment above: you don't even need any sort of fancy data structure.

Here's a really simple piece of code (error handling and other bells & whistles omitted for clarity) that generates variations with repetition:

```
char the_string[] = "abc12def34";
char *digit_pos[strlen(the_string)];
char replacements[] = "XYZ";
int n = strlen(replacements);

// memoize all digit positions
int k = 0;
for (char *p = the_string; *p; p++)
    if (isdigit(*p))
        digit_pos[k++] = p;

// generate all variations
int bound = pow(n, k);
for (int i = 0; i < bound; i++) {
    // convert 'i' to its digits;
    // use them to index into replacements array
    int tmp = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        *digit_pos[j] = replacements[tmp % n];
        tmp /= n;
    }

    printf("%s\n", the_string);
}
```

Comment: `n` can be `26` and `k` typically `10`, pow(n, k) far exceeds `MAX_INT`.  Furthermore, your algorithm may replace the same digit with a different letter in different places.

Comment: @chqrlie and for some large values of `pow(n, k)`, the floating-point representation may not be able to hold the exact integer value, yadda yadda… this is just a demonstration. I'm not intending to write all of OP's homework. as to your second comment: exactly, that's what "variations with repetition" means.

Comment: The OP states: *so each number 0,1,2,... gets its letter (not necessarily unique)*.  Aside from the misuse of number for digit, it is not clear whether he same digit appearing multiples times in the string is supposed to be replaced by the same letter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive algorithm that I think more closely matches your use case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printone(const char *alphabet, int rep[], const char *str) {
    char buf[strlen(str) + 1];
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0; (c = str[i]) != '\0'; i++) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            c = alphabet[rep[c - '0']];
        buf[i] = (char)c;
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';
    puts(buf);
}

int printrec(const char *alphabet, int alen, int rep[], int digit, int maxd, const char *str) {
    int count = 0;
    for (;; digit++) {
        if (digit >= maxd) {
            printone(alphabet, rep, str);
            return 1;
        }
        if (!strchr(str, '0' + digit))
            continue;

        for (rep[digit] = 0; rep[digit] < alen; rep[digit]++) {
            count += printrec(alphabet, alen, rep, digit + 1, maxd, str);
        }
        return count;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s alphabet string\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    } else {
        int rep[10];
        int count = printrec(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]), rep, 0, 10, argv[2]);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d combinations\n", count);
        return 0;
    }
}
```